# How can I change color in tag of html when I press a button?

Tags: javascript

I need to change color an element in tag of html from black to red and to return color black again. I have a simple button it to add 1.

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="e">0</div>
    <input type="button" onclick="foo()" value="Ok">

    <script>
        var e = 0
        function foo(){
            kak = document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = e += 1
        }   
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("e").style.color = "red";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by adding a class to the element, and then tie that class to a color style through css. Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #input-button { background-color: black; color: white; }
      #input-button.red { background-color: red }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="e">0</div>
    <input id="input-button" type="button" onclick="foo()" value="Ok">

    <script>
      var e = 0
      function foo(){
        var el = document.getElementById('e');
        el.innerHTML = e += 1;

        var button = document.getElementById('input-button');
        button.classList.add('red');

        // setTimeout begins a timer, and I pass 500ms. To
        // make this longer, increase the number below
        setTimeout(function(){
          button.classList.remove('red');
        }, 500)

      }  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's an example
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wq0kLvq/)